# Lambda expression (Python )

Tags: python, function, lambda

- Can anyone please help me what code should be like for this question ?

Q Write a **lambda expression** and assign it to the variable evensquared such that it squares the value of its single argument if the argument is even, and cubes the argument if it is odd.

Afterward, for example, expression **evensquared(5)** should yield 125, while **evensquared(4)** should yield 16.

### Hint: We need an expression to handle an if type condition.

--> Down below should work.

```
assert(evensquared(1)==1)
assert(evensquared(2)==4)
assert(evensquared(3)==27)
assert(evensquared(4)==16)
assert(evensquared(0)==0)
```

Comment: Do you know how to write a lambda expression? Do you know how to write a conditional expression?

Comment: I conceptually know it, but not really. So I'd like to learn through this example

Comment: The mentioning of `Hint` suggest Homework

Answer (score 1):

```py
evensquared = lambda x: x**2 if (x%2 == 0) else x**3
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted since answers the OP's post

Comment: @JohnGreenfield I don't know why? But it was downvoted within 1 minute of answering it, after which I got confused why someone would downvote a correct answer, which also made me think whether answering simple questions is good or bad here.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function using if else:

```
lambda <value> : <return value if <(expression)> <else expression>
```

In your case, you need to assign to a variable called evensquared:

```
evensquared = lambda num : num**2 if (num % 2==0) else num**3
```